# Is non-trivial constructor in IoC paradigm a bad thing?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

I'm using dependency injection in my C# projects and generally everything is ok.
Nevertheless, I often hear the rule "constructor must only consist of trivial operations - assign dependencies and do nothing more" I.e:

```
//dependencies
interface IMyFooDependency
{
   string GetBuzz();
   int DoOtherStuff();
}

interface IMyBarDependency
{
  void CrunchMe();
}

//consumer
class MyNiceConsumer
{
  private readonly IMyFooDependency foo;
  private readonly  IMyBarDependency bar;
  private /*readonly*/ string buzz;//<---question here
  MyNiceConsumer(IMyFooDependency foo, IMyBarDependency bar)
  { 
     //omitting null checks
     this.foo = foo;
     this.bar = bar;
     //OR
     this.buzz = foo.GetBuzz();//is this a bad thing to do? 
  }  
}
```

**UPD**: assume `IMyFooDependency` can't be replaced with the `GetBuzz()`, as in that case the answer is obvious: "do not depend on `foo`".

**UPD2**: Please, understand that this question is not about eliminating dependency from foo in a hypothetic code, but about understanding a principle of good constructor design.

So, my questions is following: is this really a **bad pattern** to include non-trivial logic in constructor(i.e. obtaining `buzz` value, making some calculations based on dependencies.)

Personally I, unless lazy load is necessary, would include `foo.GetBuzz()` in constructor, as object need to be initialized after call to its constructor.

The only drawback I see: by including non-trivial logic you increase the number of places where something might go wrong, and you'll get an obfuscated error message from your IoC container(but same things happen in case of invalid parameter, so the drawback is rather minor)

Any other considerations for eliding non-trivial constructors?

Comment: If IMyFooDependency is only used to invoke GetBuzz, then:don't depend on IMyFooDependency. Change the parameter to `string buzz` and remove the member `foo`.

Comment: But what if If IMyFooDependency acts like a repository and replacing it with just a value is highly undesirable? And nevertheless, the question remains.

Comment: You could leave the assignment of buzz to later through a use of a lazy load pattern, either in a property accessor or the lazy(t) class in .net 4.0.

Comment: Constructors throwing exceptions might be a problem, especially if inheritance is involved.

Comment: what is that problem? how can a constructor say without exception that a problem occured and object is not valid?

Comment: I'll blindly trust Herb Sutter with that: http://herbsutter.com/2008/07/25/constructor-exceptions-in-c-c-and-java/

Comment: I respect Herb Sutter, he is a great C++ expert, but in  article you mentioned, he is discussing IDisposable C# objects , that are not in scope of my question.

Comment: Actually you don't have other options to initialize readonly fields

Answer (score 1):

If you need `IMyFooDependency` only for `buzz` creation, then you actually need buzz:

```
class MyNiceConsumer
{
  private readonly IMyBarDependency bar;
  private readonly string buzz;

  MyNiceConsumer(string buzz, IMyBarDependency bar)
  { 
     this.buzz = buzz;
     this.bar = bar;
  }  
}
```

And create instance of nice consumer this way:

```
new MyNiceConsumer(foo.GetBuzz(), bar);
```

I don't see any difference between obtaining buzz before passing parameters to constructor, or obtaining it inside constructor. Same value will be returned from repository. So, you don't need to depend on repository.

UPDATE: Technically there is nothing wrong with complex initialization logic in constructor. Take a look on winforms `InitializeComponent` method, where all controls are created, initialized and added to form.

But it violates SRP (creation and initialization) and its hard to test. You can read more about this flaw [on writing testable code guide](http://misko.hevery.com/code-reviewers-guide/flaw-constructor-does-real-work/). Main idea:

> Do not create collaborators in your constructor, but pass them in.
>   (Don’t look for things! Ask for things!)

Comment: What if you want to decouple the code that constructs `MyNiceConsumer` from `foo`, i.e., the constructing code treats `foo` as an opaque value for design purposes?

Comment: Actually we don't know anything about code that constructs `MyNiceConsumer` (besides it has instances of foo and bar), so only thing I can say definitely - consumer is not dependent on foo, and we can create consumer that way

Answer (score 1):

The rationale for not doing any work in the constructor comes from looking at the execution of the program in two phases. The first phase is to wire up your object graph. The second phase is to do the "real work".

There is a tension between this ideal and efficiently maintaining a class's invariants and internal state. The less setup you can do in your constructor, the more difficult all of your methods will be to implement because they must take into account the varying possible internal state of the object. Remember, the constructor is the only code you can be sure is called for an object.

The way out of this conundrum is to realize that an object's "real work" is defined by it's interface and behavior in relation to other objects. That is, the dependencies provided to the constructor and objects provided as arguments to methods later down the road.

Feel free to do any kind of setup you like in your constructor that does not have a noticeable effect on other objects in your system. Likewise, be very sensitive to timing issues in your object's construction.

If you determine that a File object can't exist without a filename provided by the user: don't call keyboard.filename_from_keyboard() in the constructor. Instead you design your system such that the object is created by a factory (provider) during execution with the filename provided to the constructor or you allow the File object to exist without a filename. Maybe it can get it's own filename during execution? This is part of managing your object's lifetime and it's the hardest part IMO. This gets very subtle because "real work" involves creating objects too. But I digress...

In your example you would have to decide if foo.GetBuzz() breaks that condition. If GetBuzz() is a referentially transparent function, you're almost always in the clear to call it in the constructor. If GetBuzz() involves any I/O, user interaction or changes any noticeable internal state of any other object, then it is probably does not need to be called from a constructor.

Comment: Nice considerations. However, how I can know (in general case), that some method call in **interface** will involve I/O , or network call? It is abstracted away!

Comment: Obviously you want to err on the side of NOT calling the method in the constructor. Generally speaking, don't do it ever. This a weak form of coupling that you have to evaluate on a case by case basis.

Comment: You asked about including non-trivial logic. If you know that a method call is non-trivial or trivial on another object, then you've already pierced the abstraction boundary with your knowledge of the inner workings of the other object. If that really bothers you (and it should at least a little bit), assume every operation is non-trivial and do nothing in the constructor. This is the most pessimistic view you can take.

Answer (score 0):

As lazyberezovsky rightly mentioned, don't look for things! Ask for things!

If the creating code (let's say, `MyNiceCreator`) treats `foo` as an opaque value and news up `MyNiceConsumer`, then most likely creation should not be the responsibility of `MyNiceCreator`. The code that creates the `MyNiceConsumer` instance must be able to give the required values to the constructor.
A better pattern:
`MyNiceCreator` should "ask" for a `MyNiceConsumer` instance. This way the creation of `MyNiceConsumer` instance will be the responsibility of the appropriate class.